# SVN : Cannot load /mod_status.so into server: The specified module could not be found.

Tags: apache, svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

We have installed VisualSVN Server 2.5.8 in windows server 2012 R2. while loading the the module 'mod_status.so' in httpd-custom.conf, we are getting the following error,

```
"VisualSVNServer.exe: Syntax error on line 129 of C:/Program Files (x86)/VisualSVN Server/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 7 of C:/Program Files (x86)/VisualSVN Server/conf/httpd-custom.conf: Cannot load C:/Program Files (x86)/VisualSVN Server/bin/mod_status.so into server: The specified module could not be found."
```

But the module is exist in the 'C:/Program Files (x86)/VisualSVN Server/Bin' folder. we are able to load the module in other windows machines successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the mod_status.so is there? I don't think so unless you placed some custom module there. VisualSVN Server comes with mod_status module starting with version 3.0.0, so mod_status has to be missing in 2.5.8.

**IMPORTANT:** You should never load modules that are not included with VisualSVN Server distribution. VisualSVN Team can't guarantee that the custom-built modules will be loaded or operate properly. Please use the modules that are included with VisualSVN Server distribution only.

Therefore, you should upgrade the server to the latest 3.5 release if you want to enable mod_status.

---

Don't forget that VisualSVN Server 2.5 is already out of support. It is strongly recommended to upgrade your server instance to the latest version, [VisualSVN Server 3.5](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/3.5/). Please read [KB95: Upgrading to VisualSVN Server 3.5](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00095/) guide before beginning the upgrade. For the complete list of changes between version 2.5 and 3.5, take a look at the [changelog](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/).

I have to note that VisualSVN Server 2.5.8 is **very outdated**. It's not just behind 5 major updates, but behind 16 minor patch updates. You should always apply the latest patch updates to the server.

Applying a patch update is always painless and fast; patch updates contain only bug fixes and no new features. Just download and run the installer of newer version from the download page.

VisualSVN Team timely releases maintenance updates for VisualSVN Server with security and bugfixes, and it is strongly recommended to keep VisualSVN Server at the latest version. The list of fixed vulnerabilities is available for every release in VisualSVN Server's [changelog](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/) and on the [release announcements](https://www.visualsvn.com/company/news/) page.

To receive release announcements, subscribe to the [official announcements list](https://www.visualsvn.com/company/subscribe/) or [RSS feed](https://www.visualsvn.com/rss.xml). You can also follow VisualSVN Team on Twitter [@VisualSVN](https://twitter.com/visualsvn) or [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/VisualSVN).